# "can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str" Python to PLC Connection

Tags: python, concatenation, plc

I was trying to read data from PLC Micro Logics 1400(Allen Bradley) through Python and dump it to MS SQL, then **"can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str"** this error occurred while reading data from PLC Micro Logics 1400. I will attach the python program which I am currently using. If anyone knows the solution for this kindly help me out with it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C-g4M5YhtsvvTCaDnz3jLhYuRg64E-8f/view?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code that produces this error **in the question itself**.

Comment: Also, consider using the [search tool first](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=can+only+concatenate+str+%28not+%22bytes%22%29+to+str)

Answer (score 0):

convert `bytes` data into `str` by using `decode` method on the `bytes` object.

For example,

```
hello = b"Hello"
print(type(hello))
>> <class 'bytes'>

hello.decode("utf-8")
print(type(hello))
>> <class 'str'>
```

Then you can concatenate `bytes` object with `str`.

*(`"utf-8"` is a type of encoding, you need to identify the type of encoding to be used to decode the byte object without error)